# UITabBar: Set Icon Color as Pattern Image

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uicolor

Is there a way to set the icon color in a `UITabBar` as a pattern image vs. a solid color?

One would think that the following would accomplish this:

```
tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "my_image")!);
```

However, the above does not make the tab bar icon color that of the pattern image.